# How can I daily auto increment an org-mode integer property?

Tags: org-mode

Not sure if this is a thing, but I'd like new tasks that are added with property SWAY=1, which is sort of a priority, to auto-increment by 1 for each day that passes.

This means that old tasks will gradually move up the priority chain.

The list of files would be org-agenda-files;)

Comment: Sure you can, but do you really want to implement your own mechanism? If you `SCHEDULE` your tasks, your agenda will show how many days have gone by for any that are still open. They will disappear from the agenda once you close them.

Comment: I've learned to never schedule anything, except things that I absolutely have to do, like dentist and vehicle repair appointments. I find that tasks that are possible to do at a later time, I always do at a later time. I don't have the discipline of Tyson, and I never will and don't even want to, so all my tasks become OVERDUE. That's why I use SWAY to prioritize my backlog.

Comment: OK I guess (how to manage a backlog is a large topic indeed). You should specify how to find those tasks. Are they in a single file, in your agenda files, in some other set of files (and if so, how do you specify that set)? Once you have the set of files, looping through them (either manually if the specification is ad-hoc or by using the appropriate scope in `org-map-entries`) will allow you to call `org-map-entries` with a function that updates the `SWAY` property on each relevant headline. See  [Mapping API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html) and ...

Comment: ... [Property API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Property-API.html) in the manual. You can then run this function at midnight (or shortly thereafter) using a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the heart of the implementation as described above. It still needs clarification by the OP on what file(s) contain the affected tasks (which has now been offered: see the EDIT below); it currently just updates the tasks in the current buffer - and it does not even save the buffer - but it is enough to illustrate how to do the basic implementation task: increment the value of any entry that has a `SWAY` property. Once the OP clarifies the question of which file(s) contain the tasks that should be affected, the wrapper function that loops through the relevant set of files can be written, and a timer implemented to run the wrapper function at midnight every day.

Here's the code:

```el
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun sway+ ()
    "If the headline at point contains a property called SWAY,
  increment its value and update the property. It is assumed that
  the value of the property is a string representing a number: if
  that is not the case, this function is at the mercy of
  `string-to-number' whose conversions might not always make
  sense. More stringent checking is left as an exercise."
     
    (let ((val (org-entry-get nil "SWAY")))
      (when val
        (org-entry-put nil "SWAY" (number-to-string (1+ (string-to-number val)))))))

   ;;; Call the sway+ function on any headline in the current buffer
   ;;; that has a non-empty SWAY property.
   (org-map-entries #'sway+ "SWAY<>\"\"" 'file)
#+end_src
```

EDIT: The OP has clarified that the list of files containing these tasks are files in the `org-agenda-files` list. That makes things easier, since `org-map-entries` allows an `agenda` scope which makes it loop internally over all the agenda files: all we have to do is change the `file` scope above to `agenda`. We still want to wrap it in a function that we can give to the timer, so the final implementation looks like this:

```el
;;; sway+ is exactly the same as before

;;; the timer fires at 1min after midnight. We save the timer object
;;; in a global variable, so that we can get hold of the timer and
;;; kill it later on - if necessary.

(defvar my/update-sway-property-timer)

;;; update-sway-property-and-reset-timer wraps the `org-map-entries` call
(defun update-sway-property-and-reset-timer ()
      (org-map-entries #'sway+ "SWAY<>\"\"" 'agenda)
      (setq my/update-sway-property-timer (run-at-time "24:01" nil #'update-sway-property-and-reset-timer)))

;;; get the ball rolling
(setq my/update-sway-property-timer (run-at-time "24:01" nil #'update-sway-property-and-reset-timer))

;;; to get rid of the timer, do `C-x C-e` after the closing paren
;;; (cancel-timer my/update-sway-property-timer)
```

I don't remember where I learnt the `24:01` trick but it has served me faithfully for many years. Instead of setting up a repeating timer, we set up a one-shot timer for 1 minute past midnight "today": that correctly sets the time for 00:01 *tomorrow*. When the timer fires, the function that it runs does whatever it is supposed to do and in addition, sets a new timer for `24:01` "today" and the cycle repeats.

This is now tested: I deleted some wayward extra parens, fixed the wrapper function name everywhere, got rid of an extra `defun` and tested with a simple setup: two "agenda" files with a handful of entries each, some containing a `SWAY` property, some not. I shortened the timers to a minute and it all went according to plan. Let me know if you run into any problems.

Comment: DId you miss this answer? It's been here for a week and all I've got is ... crickets. Please try it and provide some feedback. Thanks!

Comment: It looks perfect and I need a few days to test it;) Thank you very much. I'll report back;)

Comment: Also, I did not receive a notification about your comment here; I just happened to return to this todo. I'll check my notification settings.

Comment: Check some of your other questions going back six months or so: I pinged you on a bunch of them.

Comment: Weird, I did receive a notification now. Yes, sure, I'll go through all of them.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly;). Now I have the problem of large commit files every day, which is harder to review. I'm not sure this was a good idea, but I do like the creeping priorities, for now;). Thanks.