# How can I org-depend on a date?

Tags: org-mode

I don't think org-depend can depend on a date, but maybe org-edna can?

I find lots of org-edna examples, but not the actual documentation where it would list date as an option.

What I want is for a org-heading to change state to TODO after a certain date.

I can't use scheduling, cause it's not considered overdue, if I am free to do it any time after that date.

Something, like

```
:BLOCKER: not_before(2023-12-24)
```

Comment: This could easily be done the same way as in your [SWAY question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/79802/how-can-i-daily-auto-increment-an-org-mode-integer-property): a timer triggers a function every night and the function searches all heading for a `NOT-BEFORE` property - if it finds it, it compares the date in the property with the current date and if they are equal, it sets the TODO state.